# Close radwindow using button inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a popup radwindow in every page. I want to close the popup using close button inside it. I have searched through the web but did not get any luck. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:
Mainpage.aspx

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ReportDialog" Src="~/WebUserControl/ReportDialog.ascx" %>
<telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindowReportDialog" runat="server" VisibleTitlebar="true"
    Title="Report" VisibleStatusbar="false" Width="415px" Height="355px" ReloadOnShow="true"
    ShowContentDuringLoad="true" Behaviors="Move, Close" Modal="true" OnClientBeforeClose="RadWindowReportDialog_OnClientBeforeClose">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:ReportDialog ID="ReportDialog" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

ReportDialog.ascx

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="rbutton" OnClick="btnClose_Click"
                            Text="Close" Width="90px" OnClientLoad="btnClose_OnClientLoad" >
                            <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../Image/Close.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" />
                        </telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

ascx

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="rbutton" OnClick="btnClose_Click"
                            Text="Close" Width="90px" OnClientLoad="btnClose_OnClientLoad" >
                            <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../Image/Close.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" OnClientClicked="OnClientClicked"/>
                        </telerik:RadButton>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientClicked(sender, args) {
        var window= $find('<%=RadWindowReportDialog.ClientID %>');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but I got this error Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'RadWindowReportDialog' does not exist in the current context